# PrepareRequestUserAuthorizationAsync fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dotnetopenauth

I had very simple code which worked fine for me:

```
var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
Uri callbackUrl = new System.Uri(url, "oAuth2CallBack");

var ub = new UriBuilder(callbackUrl);
// decodes urlencoded pairs from uri.Query to var
var httpValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(callbackUrl.Query);
httpValueCollection.Add(UrlArguments.Param, null);

// urlencodes the whole HttpValueCollection
ub.Query = httpValueCollection.ToString();

var authorizationRequest = OAuthClient.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(new[] { "somedata" }, ub.Uri);
authorizationRequest.Send();
```

I've updated OAuth's NuGet packages and rewrite the code this way:

```
var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
Uri callbackUrl = new System.Uri(url, "oAuth2CallBack");


var ub = new UriBuilder(callbackUrl);
// decodes urlencoded pairs from uri.Query to var
var httpValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(callbackUrl.Query);
httpValueCollection.Add(UrlArguments.Param, null);

// urlencodes the whole HttpValueCollection
ub.Query = httpValueCollection.ToString();

var client = new WebServerClient(new AuthorizationServerDescription
{
    TokenEndpoint = Configuration.OAuth2.TokenEndpoint,
    AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration.OAuth2.AuthorizationEndpoint,
},
                clientIdentifier: Configuration.OAuth2.ClientIdentifier,
                clientCredentialApplicator: ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(
                                        Configuration.OAuth2.ClientSecret));

var authorizationRequest = await client.PrepareRequestUserAuthorizationAsync(new[] { "somedata" }, ub.Uri);
await authorizationRequest.SendAsync();
```

but `PrepareRequestUserAuthorizationAsync` throws exception

> "Attempt by method
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient+d__3.MoveNext()'
>   to access method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor()' failed."

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting this too, can't find any documentation on it, it happen on the var cookies = new List<CookieHeaderValue>(); line ...

Comment: same for me as for @TobyEvans !!

Comment: In the end, I got the source and commented out the cookie code that causes the error, works now, but I'm not happy going to production with that

Comment: I have this issue too, but am not really comfortable commenting out a security feature. Maybe @andrew arnott can shed some light on this.

Comment: Did u try synchronous request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client references System.Net.Http.Formatters 5.0 from the WebApi nuget package.  Setting the reference to System.Net.Http.Formatters 4.0 from the .NET 4.0/4.5 BCL resolves the issue and all tests still pass.

See commit on github
https://github.com/rcollette/DotNetOpenAuth/commit/59fe1e820fc48df8bb079b210ac585974f8326f5

See pull request
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/pull/350